# Ansible logic to have same user sudo at some instances whereas normal at other instances

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to build a simple logic where the same user as sudo at box/instance-(A and B) but to have it as normal user at instance-(C and D).

I have a variable `is_sudo` which is a boolean and I am checking if its true then to have the user in sudoers, and it works perfect if the condition is same throughout the setups. Now I want to have some condition in which if instance is C or D then the user should get created as normal user. I am thinking to overwrite the dict variable value to set it false over those instances but it seems is not possible to overwrite the dict variable on the fly.

Example:

*var/main.yml* [from userupdate role]

```yaml
users:
  - username: user1
    is_sudo: true
  - username: user2
    is_sudo: false
```

*host1.yml*

```yaml
roles:
  - userupdate
vars:
  users:
    username: user1
    is_sudo: false
```

If there is anything quick?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). The `play vars` (precedence 12.) won't override the `role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)` (precedence 15). There are more options on how to override `role vars`. For example, use `role params` (precedence 20). See [Using roles at the play level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level)

```yaml
    roles:
      - role: userupdate
        users:
          - username: user1
            is_sudo: false
```

---

Notes

- This is the only option for how to override role vars at the play level. Other options (precedence 16,17,18,19) are at the task level.
- Correct role's directory is `vars` not `var`. The comment should be `# cat vars/main.yml [from userupdate role]`.
- The variable `users` is a list. This shouldn't be probably changed on the fly too.
- The variable `users` will be overridden not merged.
- Read comments in [Role Variables leak to other Roles when using vars #66610](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66610#issuecomment-579863438). Quoting:

The following format is called `role params`:

```yaml
roles:
  - role: foo
    foo: bar
```

Whereas the following are `vars`:

```yaml
roles:
  - role: foo
    vars:
      foo: bar
```

---

**Merge updates**

If you want to merge the updates change the structure to the dictionary and `combine` the common and updates. For example

```yaml
shell> cat roles/userupdate/vars/main.yml
users_common:
  user1:
    is_sudo: true
  user2:
    is_sudo: false
users: "{{ users_common|combine(users_update|default({})) }}"

shell> cat roles/userupdate/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: users
```

Then the invocation of the role

```yaml
  roles:
    - role: userupdate
      users_update:
        user1:
          is_sudo: false
```

gives

```yaml
  users:
    user1:
      is_sudo: false
    user2:
      is_sudo: false
```

Comment: ohh wow! what a great explanation! Yes this is the expected and correct way of doing it. Thanks for guiding over this @Vladimir. This is great!

Comment: ok, so I tried this approach and made it working. The only issue is I need to define all the key:value pair in that dict item, for example, in above I was having is_sudo, name, shell, etc other key values which I had to redefine again at role invocation to make it work correctly. Still thats fine and manageable. Thanks for guiding through this.